# How to Unit Test a custom JsonConverter in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mocking, httprequest

I have a custom JsonConverter that takes a local datetime string from the front-end and converts it to `DateTimeOffset` using NodaTime.

I replaced the default resolver in Json.NET.

```
formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
              Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
              ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
              ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
          };
```

So in my tests I need to make sure I configure this.

What happens under-the-hood is that a POST request is made to my API controller. If the ViewModel (that is used in the API action) contains a `DateTimeOffset` property, then the associated JSON datetime property goes through the converter.

When the converter is triggered, then the application first gets the `User.Identity`:

```
var user = (ClaimsIdentity) Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
```

Upon success we extract the `Locality` claim, which contains the IANA timezone ID (e.g. "America/New_York").

We use this to convert the local datetime to the corresponding DateTimeOffset.

This is what I want to test.

I have the JSON object:

```
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection() {
            {"dateCreated", "2015-11-30T14:22:00+1:00"},
            {"message", "Some message."},
            {"timelinePostId", "1"},
            {"applicationUser", ""},
            {"thumbs","" }
        };
```

But I'm stuck on how to perform the --

```
// Arrange

// Act

// Assert
```

I found this MockHelper class, so I have this ready for use.

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext(HttpVerbs verbs, NameValueCollection nameValueCollection)
{
    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser { 
            Id = "abc", 
            TimezoneId = "America/New_York" 
        };

    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    request.Setup(c => c.Form).Returns(nameValueCollection);
    request.Setup(c => c.QueryString).Returns(nameValueCollection);
    request.Setup(c => c.RequestType).Returns(verbs.ToString().ToUpper());

    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    httpContext.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

    var u = verbs.ToString().ToUpper();

    httpContext.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    httpContext.Setup(c => c.Server).Returns(server.Object);
    httpContext.Setup(c => c.User.Identity.GetUserId()).Returns("abc");
    httpContext.Setup(c => c.User.ApplicationUser()).Returns(user);
    return httpContext.Object;
}
```

So I have my JSON mock and I have my Identity mock, but how do I get it to work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this kinda stuff drives me nuts when designing my web api controllers. They make it look so easy in tutorials.. then, you do real world stuff.. and you really do end up mocking the entire web pipeline.. what a mess!  I also have a special POCO that I've designed a JSON conversion for that is registered by the GlobalConfiguration.. ugh!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't require mocking the entire HttpContext.

In your JsonConverter class, refactor the logic in `ReadJson` to a separate method, passing in the Identity object:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    return DeserializeDate(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer, (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
}

public object DeserializeDate(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer, ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Then write your unit tests against `DeserializeDate`.